# Deconvolution layers in keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am trying to design a CNN architecture in keras python. I want to transform (for my decoder) form the deconvoluation layer 5 (512 filters with filter size 4x4) to the next layer (using deconvolution2D) and to go to deconvolution layer 6 128 filters with filter size `7x7`. How can I do that deconvolution? What I tried is the following:

```
d6 = Deconvolution2D(128, 5, 5, subsample=(2,2),  activation='relu',init='uniform', output_shape=(None, 128, 7, 7), border_mode='same')(d6)
```

However, this operation leads to 128 filters with size `8x8`. How can I have instead `7x7`?

I am trying also to go from `(8x8)` to `(7x7)` using simply convolution by choosing as filter size `(3x3)` and the same number of filters:

```
d6 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3,   activation='relu', border_mode='same')(d6)
```

However, the result in the end is again the same `(128,8,8)` instead of `(128, 7, 7)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the problem is that you're using an even number for `subsample` (currently "strides") and an odd number for the image size.

With `subsample=(2,2)`, you will necessarily half the size of the image, so the inverse convolution will necessarily double the size of the image. There is nothing you can do here, unless you start working with 8x8 or remove the `subsample`. (If you start playing too much with combinations of kernel size, border mode and subsample, you may achieve the 7 x 7, but besides being a confusing math, it may also create an unbalanced image, more to the left or more to the right, for instance. This may affect the results when your images are that small)

In the second case, the result is the same because you're using `border_mode='same'`. But if you remove this, you sizes will go from 8x8 to 6x6. You'd need a filter size of (2,2) to lose only one pixel.

---

I suggest you to move to Keras 2.

Example:

```
#but I suggest you remove the strides
d6 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (5,5), strides = (2,2), activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='uniform')

#'valid' is the default value, but I wrote it so you see the new name of "border_mode"
d6 = Conv2D(128,(3,3), activation='relu', padding='valid')(d6)
```

Comment: I think the issue was the usage of Convolution2D instead of Conv2D, when i changed it worked properly. Convolution2D does not do what i want even if you have filter_size  =(2, 2).